# Limit the fields being requested via Azure APIM

Tags: azure-api-management

We are using Azure APIM wrapped around the Dynamics365 API.  We have it up and running but what I would like to do is limit the fields/attributes that are returned via the APIM.

I.e., we have a method called Contacts, but I don't want to return 200 fields, just the ones we want to be exposed via the APIM.

There is a walkthrough on how to do this on the response, but I would like to filter on the initial request (i.e., the SELECT in the Web API).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies

I have tried playing around with this nomenclature in the INBOUND header to no avail.

```
<choose>
  <when condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode == 200 && context.Product.Name.Equals("Starter"))">
    <set-body>@{
        var response = context.Response.Body.As<JObject>();
        foreach (var key in new [] {"current", "minutely", "hourly", "daily", "alerts"}) {
          response.Property (key).Remove ();
        }
        return response.ToString();
      }
    </set-body>
  </when>
</choose>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, all you need is to use [set-query-parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetQueryStringParameter) policy:

```
<set-query-parameter name="$select" exists-action="override ">
    <value>firstname,nickname</value>
</set-query-parameter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform the input payload. Use the payload transformation logic inside the APIM policy. One example is using liquid templates and passing the only required fields. You can refer the documentation here : https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies.md#using-liquid-templates-with-set-body